# PHP Products export

Tags: php, xml, prestashop

I have PrestaShop XML module which exports products.

I want that my category_name, category_id and category_link would be in father. For example:

```xml
<categories>
<category_name></category_name>
<category_id></category_id>
<category_link></category_link>
</categories>
```

What I need to change in this code:

```php
$xmlProduct = $this->document->createElement('product');
$xmlProduct->setAttribute('id', $xmlProductId);
$xmlProduct->appendChild($this->getCDATAElement('title', $xmlProductName));
$xmlProduct->appendChild($this->document->createElement('price', $xmlProductPrice));
$xmlProduct->appendChild($this->document->createElement('stock', $product['quantity']));
$xmlProduct->appendChild($this->document->createElement('product_url', $xmlProductUrl));
$xmlProduct->appendChild($this->document->createElement('category_id', $product['id_category_default']));
$xmlProduct->appendChild($this->getCDATAElement('category_name', $product['category']));
$xmlProduct->appendChild($this->document->createElement('category_link', $productProvider->getCategoryLink($product['id_category_default'], $product['category_rewrite'])));
```

I tried to change, but I don't have enough knowledge in PHP to solve that.

Comment: You would have to create a `categories` element first (why plural though?), and then append the `category_name`, `category_id` and `category_link` elements to _that one_, instead of the `product` element.

Comment: @CBroe okay, thank you. How should I create one extra line? I mean what I need to write. Thanks...

Comment: @Ignas StackOverflow is not a code writing service, you will need to show considerable effort in solving the problem and describing what you've tried and what didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `categories` sub element and add child elements to that:

```php
$xmlProduct = $this->document->createElement('product');
$xmlProduct->setAttribute('id', $xmlProductId);
$xmlProduct->appendChild($this->getCDATAElement('title', $xmlProductName));
$xmlProduct->appendChild($this->document->createElement('price', $xmlProductPrice));
$xmlProduct->appendChild($this->document->createElement('stock', $product['quantity']));
$xmlProduct->appendChild($this->document->createElement('product_url', $xmlProductUrl));

$xmlCategories = $this->document->createElement('categories');
$xmlCategories->appendChild($this->document->createElement('category_id', $product['id_category_default']));
$xmlCategories->appendChild($this->getCDATAElement('category_name', $product['category']));
$xmlCategories->appendChild($this->document->createElement('category_link', $productProvider->getCategoryLink($product['id_category_default'], $product['category_rewrite'])));
$xmlProduct->appendChild($xmlCategories);
```